# How to get a name of a number based on its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a function `getNumName()` which, when given a number, will output a string that is that number's name and vice versa. I have not been able to achieve the former nor the latter, but the latter I've gotten frustratingly close to:

```
function getNameNum(num){    // string => num
    var x = document.createElement("div");
    $(x).load("https://www.google.com/search?q="+num+"+plus+zero #cwos");
    return x.innerHTML;
}
```

Which would force Google to return its calculator, then grab that number, and return it. However, I get a CORS (Cross-Origin Request Blocked) error (Darn! Google has protection!). I had an idea for a solution for the former:

```
function getNumName(num){    // num -> string
    var names = ["zero","one","two","three","four",...]
    return names[+num];
}
```

But this seems highly impractical. If I have these two functions for the natural numbers, I can easily extend it to the negative numbers (with `Math.sign().replace("-","negative ")`), then extend that to the real numbers (`num+"".split(".")[1].split("").forEach(...)...`).

The big problem is: How can I achieve these two functions? I am willing to use an external library of sorts and jQuery.

1. `getNameNum() -> name => num`
2. `getNumName() -> num => name`

Comment: This may help:http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using code from [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm):

```
var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function toWords(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
    var n = s.split('');
    var str = '';
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += 'point ';
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
    }
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
}
```

Comment: it's missing this declaration in the beginning:

var th = ['','thousand','million', 'milliard','billion'];

I've created a stackblitz with a working example using Angular pipe:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u9klet?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts